# Magento admin - change default Configuration menu

Tags: magento

When I login to admin and navigate to **System >> Configuration**, I have an Inchoo Featured Products menu that is already open. I want this to default to **General >> General**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

Go to /app/code/local/[companyName]/[moduleName]/etc/system.xml

```
<config>
    ......
    <sections>
        <xyz translate="label" module="xyz">
             .....
             <sort_order>1</sort_order>
```

Change the `<sort_order>1</sort_order>` to a larger number eg `<sort_order>96</sort_order>`

(this is how other module does it, not sure if they uses the same method)