# Custom System Config Tab View Issues in Magento Admin panel

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

i have created the new custom config TAB in admin panel configuration section under the `System > Configuration`. I have referred the below link for system config **TAB** Creation
http://www.johannreinke.com/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/

My problem is When i click the Configuration Menu Under the System, Our Custom Tab Always Show instead of General Tab. I Need to Show the General Tab Always instead of showing my custom TAB.

Can anyone look the above my reference link and give me a suggestion for my issues?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your sort_order /app/code/local/[companyName]/[moduleName]/etc/system.xml

```
<config>
    ......
    <sections>
        <xyz translate="label" module="xyz">
             .....
             <sort_order>1</sort_order>
```

Try change it to a larger number eg `<sort_order>96</sort_order>`

See [Magento admin - change default Configuration menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407870/magento-admin-change-default-configuration-menu)